# Running tests in Laravel 4 yields "Unknown method User::save()"

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have added `phpunit` as a composer dependency, did `composer update`.

I wrote a simple test, like so:

```
$user = new User;
$user->save();
```

I run

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

or

```
vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit.xml
```

But I get

```
Undefined method User::save()
```

At the same time I can see that `$user instanceof Eloquent` is true.

Even worse - if I do `call('POST', '/posts')` I get the same problems - `Undefined method Post::save()`

Am I missing something? How to correctly run tests?

Relevant code parts:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5849706

*UPDATE*

I pushed repo to http://github.com/laravel-test-948320/bearded-bugfixes

Actually changing extends Eloquent to extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model solves the problem, but I'd still like to understand what's up.

Comment: why are you using alltests.xml instead of phpunit.xml?

Comment: Sorry, mistyped. Of course it is phpunit.xml

Comment: Can we see your `app/test/TestCase.php` file and your simple test file. Where is this file located ?

Comment: Are you sure you extended the Eloquent class in $user and $post?

Comment: @AlexandreButynski Relevant code gists: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5849706

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea. I think you can delete `Artisan::call('migrate'),` because it have not to be call in each test, but it will not resolve your issue. You can try to delete the file `bootstrap/compiled.php', it causes strange mistakes sometimes...

Comment: @AlexandreButynski I set up sqlite's `:memory:` database for fast tests, so it is empty every time. But even using usual sqlite file does not help. Deleting migrate call does not change anything. Thanks for the attempt.

Comment: can you update the gist with codes of relevant models ?

Comment: Try extending `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` instead of `Eloquent ` and see if that makes a difference. It may be an autoloading issue. Can you save models from the app? For example, can you create a model in a route and dump the result of the save function?

Comment: @Blessing Actually changing to `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` solves the problem, can you add it as an answer so that we can dig deeper into why autoloading is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I re-created your entire test-suite (I was setting up mine while reading this).
The test where all successful, so I want to know which versions you have:

- the php version
- laravel/framework version in composer.json
- the phpunit version

It is strange the a call() also results in an undefined save()...

Do you have any other packages installed or using namespaces?

Comment: I've pushed it to https://github.com/laravel-test-948320/bearded-bugfixes  (just a random name GitHub given)

Comment: You included `"app/tests/TestCase.php"` in the composer.json file. That's not required I guess. Also make sure there is no compiled.php file in the bootstrap dir.

Comment: I give up then. Go slap Taylor round a bit with a large trout.

Answer (score 1):

Try extending Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model instead of Eloquent and see if that makes a difference. It may be an autoloading issue. Can you save models from the app? For example, can you create a model in a route and dump the result of the save function?

Another question, are you loading your models via composer or the laravel ClassLoader (global.php file)? I've had trouble in the past with autoloading my classes when I use the ClassLoader.

I doubt this is a composer problem since laravel handles aliases, so dumping the autoloading shouldn't change anything. Maybe running 'artisan clear-compiled' may work if the Eloquent alias is compiled in that file.

Can't think of anything else at the moment. Anyone have other ideas?

Comment: I pushed repo to http://github.com/laravel-test-948320/bearded-bugfixes 

Actually changing extends Eloquent to extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model solves the problem, but I'd still like to understand what's up.  I can save models from app (controller), but not from tests if I extend Eloquent.

Comment: in your phpunit.xml file, is the bootstrap path correct? It is suppose to be the path to laravel's autoload.php file

Comment: This is pretty odd. I'm out of ideas but I definitely think this is an autoloading problem

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your $user and $post classes did not extend the Eloquent class.

Make sure you have this in your file:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
...
}
```

Comment: Like I said in question - "At the same time I can see that $user instanceof Eloquent is true."

Comment: I don't know what "instanceof Eloquent" does in a technical sense, but the error described tells me that it is not being extended properly.  One other thing, have you tried giving data to the $user object before saving it?  Otherwise you are just trying to save a blank set of data.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding parent::setUp() to your __construct() in your test class